# tex4ebook: nodes vanishes for TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht, tex4ebook

The test code:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}
\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand\OO{\mathcal O}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\draw[->, very thick] (-1,0) -- (-1,5);
\draw[->, very thick] (0,-1) -- (5,-1);
\draw (6,-1) node {$\Spec \OO_{C^\flat}$};
\draw (-1,5.2) node {$\Spec \Z_p$};
\draw[very thick, color=red] (0,0) -- (0,5);
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw[very thick, color=green] (0,0) -- (3.55,3.55);
\draw[color=red] (1,3.5) node {$\mathrm{crystalline}$};
\draw[color=red] (1,4.1) node {$\Spec W(k)$};
\draw[dashed] (0,5) arc [start angle=90, end angle=0, radius=5];
\draw[inner color=blue, color=white] (4,0) circle [radius=.4];
\draw[color=blue] (4,-.6) node {$\Spec W(C^\flat)$};
\draw[color=blue] (4,0.75) node {$\mathrm{\acute{e}tale}$};
\draw[color=green] (32:3.5) node {$\Spec \OO_C$};
\draw[color=green] (30:2.6) node {$\mathrm{de~Rham}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{A picture of some parts of $\Spec A_{\inf}=``\Spec \OO_{C^\flat}\times \Spec \Z_p"$.}\label{fig:Ainf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result of tex4ebook, as far as I see, the nodes vanish. I wonder a workaround for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TikZ driver for `tex4ht` doesn't support many more complicated features, especially regarding to the node  contents. It is safer to use [the alternative driver](https://github.com/michal-h21/dvisvgm4ht), which uses Dvisvgm for the SVG creation and it keeps much more details. After installation of the alternative driver, add  the following code before `\usepackage{tikz}`:

```
\ifdefined\HCode
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvisvgm4ht.def}
\fi
```

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: Is there any method to put the code about HCode somewhere (say, create a `.4ht` file) instead of modify the tex source code directly?

Comment: @Yai0Phah you can put it to another TeX file and include the main unmodified TeX file using the `\input` command.